# Why won't Angular run in Outlook 2013 as folder homepage?

Tags: angular, outlook, office-js

I am attempting to recreate this [Outlook Kanban board](https://github.com/evrenvarol/outlook-taskboard) using Angular.  I've successfully created the app and have it working in IE11.  Thinking this would be enough, I configured my Outlook 2013 instance to use it as the homepage for my task folder, and was immediately greeted with several script errors.

So I thought I'd see if I could get a bare minimum Angular app working.  I created a new project via Angular CLI, built the page and configured my Outlook task folder to use it.  I was greeted with the same script errors again:

1. 'Expected identifier' in polyfills.bundle.js

   ```
   ZoneAwarePromise.prototype.catch = function (onRejected) {
   ```
2. 'Object doesn't support property or method bind' in styles.bundle.js

   ```
   update = applyToSingletonTag.bind(null, styleElement, styleIndex, false);
   ```
3. 'Expected identifier, string or number' in vendor.bundle.js

   ```
     'zwnj': '\u200C',
   };
   ```
4. 'Object doesn't support property or method defineProperty' in main.bundle.js

   ```
   Object.defineProperty(__webpack_exports__, "__esModule", { value: true });
   ```

The third error seems to be the trailing comma on the last property definition, but the other three I don't have a clue.

Even though Outlook uses the IE engine to render webpages, it must be using an old version (IE11 is installed) or is doing some sort of emulation.  Has anyone had success getting Angular to run as a static file within Outlook?  Is there a way to utilize office-js to help resolve this?

I realize this isn't a common scenario, but thought I'd give it a shot anyway.  Seems like an easy way to visualize my Outlook tasks if I can get it working.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

After the release of Outlook 2016, Outlook version 2013 or older are considered legacy clients. To provide the best experience for our customers and make the best use of our resources we are not investing further in those versions, it is only maintained for security issues. We suggest looking at outlook module extension https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/outlook/extension-module-outlook-add-ins?product=outlook and task pane add-ins to accomplish what you are trying to do.